# Reading a dropbox file as data frame

Tags: r

I try to read from a dropbox link a csv file as data frame using this option

```
df <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/vta51y5wyzu86m1/FY_2008.csv?dl=0", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However I receive this error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

Any help to figure out why this error exist?

Comment: Have you tried the link outside of R? The text that *that* URL returns starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which means it is not the data you expect.

Comment: @r2evans thank you. I didn't try it to be honest because I took it as the sharing option link which is available from the dropbox file I have. Not sure if there is other option for the link

Comment: Load that URL into a browser window, look at Dropbox's UI, click on the "Download" and then "Direct download", and then you'll start downloading the file. Once that starts, you can determine what URL is really being used.

Comment: @r2evans thank you. I checked it. It is possible to download the file. So as I can understand I need to find another url which is not a download link but a kind of view link?

Comment: I googled `dropbox direct link`, and several of the top articles suggested changing `dl=0` to `dl=1`, please try that.

Comment: Ummm ... @foc, what type of data is this? Is it free/open data, publicy available? Does it contain any sensitive information, is it CUI or FOUO?

Comment: @r2evans they are open data from a generic site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `dl=0` to `dl=1`.

For an abbreviated demonstration, I'll limit to just the top 10 rows:

```r
df <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/vta51y5wyzu86m1/FY_2008.csv?dl=1", nrows=10)

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  65 variables:
#  $ contract_transaction_unique_key                                : chr  "9700_9700_0000_0_W91QUZ07D0011_0" "9700_9700_0001_0_DAJA6196A0004_0" "6940_6940_0001_1_DTNH2208D00115_0" "9700_9700_0001_17_F0470001D0020_0" ...
#  $ contract_award_unique_key                                      : chr  "CONT_AWD_0000_9700_W91QUZ07D0011_9700" "CONT_AWD_0001_9700_DAJA6196A0004_9700" "CONT_AWD_0001_6940_DTNH2208D00115_6940" "CONT_AWD_0001_9700_F0470001D0020_9700" ...
#  $ award_id_piid                                                  : int  0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#  $ modification_number                                            : int  0 0 1 17 2 0 0 0 1 1
#  $ transaction_number                                             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  $ parent_award_agency_id                                         : int  9700 9700 6940 9700 9700 9700 9700 9700 9700 9700
#  $ parent_award_agency_name                                       : chr  "" "DEPT OF DEFENSE" "NATIONAL HIGHWAY TRAFFIC SAFETY ADMINISTRATION" "" ...
#  $ parent_award_id_piid                                           : chr  "W91QUZ07D0011" "DAJA6196A0004" "DTNH2208D00115" "F0470001D0020" ...
#  $ parent_award_modification_number                               : chr  "0" "0" "0" "P00013" ...
#  $ federal_action_obligation                                      : num  1082099 1104 0 -15741 -15927 ...
#  $ total_dollars_obligated                                        : num  NA 1104 NA NA NA ...
#  $ current_total_value_of_award                                   : num  NA 1104 NA NA NA ...
#  $ potential_total_value_of_award                                 : num  NA 1104 NA NA NA ...
#  $ disaster_emergency_fund_codes_for_overall_award                : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ outlayed_amount_funded_by_COVID.19_supplementals_for_overall_aw: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ obligated_amount_funded_by_COVID.19_supplementals_for_overall_a: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ action_date                                                    : chr  "2008-09-30" "2008-09-30" "2008-09-30" "2008-09-30" ...
#  $ action_date_fiscal_year                                        : int  2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 2008 2008
#  $ period_of_performance_start_date                               : chr  "2008-09-30 00:00:00" "2008-09-30 00:00:00" "2008-09-30 00:00:00" "2008-09-30 00:00:00" ...
#  $ period_of_performance_current_end_date                         : chr  "2009-09-29 00:00:00" "2008-09-30 00:00:00" "2009-12-18 00:00:00" "2003-11-30 00:00:00" ...
#  $ period_of_performance_potential_end_date                       : chr  "2009-09-29 00:00:00" "2008-09-30 00:00:00" "2009-12-18 00:00:00" "2003-11-30 00:00:00" ...
#  $ awarding_agency_code                                           : int  97 97 69 97 97 97 97 97 97 97
#  $ awarding_agency_name                                           : chr  "DEPARTMENT OF DEFENSE (DOD)" "DEPARTMENT OF DEFENSE (DOD)" "DEPARTMENT OF TRANSPORTATION (DOT)" "DEPARTMENT OF DEFENSE (DOD)" ...
#  $ awarding_sub_agency_code                                       : int  2100 2100 6940 5700 5700 5700 5700 5700 5700 5700
#  $ awarding_sub_agency_name                                       : chr  "DEPT OF THE ARMY" "DEPT OF THE ARMY" "NATIONAL HIGHWAY TRAFFIC SAFETY ADMINISTRATION" "DEPT OF THE AIR FORCE" ...
#  $ awarding_office_code                                           : chr  "W911W4" "W912PA" "00022" "FA9301" ...
#  $ awarding_office_name                                           : chr  "W00Y CONTR OFC DODAAC" "ECC PARC EUROPE REGIONAL CONTRACTIN" "DEPT OF TRANS/NAT HIGHWAY TRAFFIC SAFETY ADM" "FA9301 AFTC PZIO" ...
#  $ recipient_duns                                                 : int  614948396 123456787 49508120 848288408 92440044 52220485 144606436 132004701 122474104 57579807
#  $ recipient_name                                                 : chr  "WORLD WIDE TECHNOLOGY, INC." "MISCELLANEOUS FOREIGN AWARDEES" "WESTAT, INC." "ACCENT SERVICE COMPANY INC" ...
#  $ recipient_doing_business_as_name                               : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ recipient_parent_duns                                          : int  131784451 123456787 49508120 848288408 92440044 52220485 144606436 132004701 122474104 57579807
#  $ recipient_parent_name                                          : chr  "WORLD WIDE TECHNOLOGY HOLDING CO.  INC." "MISCELLANEOUS FOREIGN CONTRACTORS" "WESTAT  INC." "ACCENT SERVICE COMPANY INC" ...
#  $ recipient_country_code                                         : chr  "USA" "USA" "UNITED STATES" "UNITED STATES" ...
#  $ recipient_country_name                                         : chr  "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA" "UNITED STATES" "" "" ...
#  $ recipient_address_line_1                                       : chr  "60 WELDON PKWY" "1800 F ST NW" "1650 RESEARCH BLVD RM RE164" "2001 LEMNOS DR" ...
#  $ recipient_address_line_2                                       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ recipient_city_name                                            : chr  "MARYLAND HEIGHTS" "WASHINGTON" "ROCKVILLE" "COSTA MESA" ...
#  $ recipient_county_name                                          : chr  "ST. LOUIS" "DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA" "" "" ...
#  $ recipient_state_code                                           : chr  "MO" "DC" "MD" "CA" ...
#  $ recipient_state_name                                           : chr  "MISSOURI" "DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA" "" "" ...
#  $ recipient_zip_4_code                                           : int  63043 204050001 208503195 926263535 92408 329205818 769047833 223031802 782584092 782073102
#  $ primary_place_of_performance_country_name                      : chr  "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA" "GERMANY" "UNITED STATES" "UNITED STATES" ...
#  $ primary_place_of_performance_city_name                         : chr  "FORT BELVOIR" "" "ROCKVILLE" "EDWARDS" ...
#  $ primary_place_of_performance_county_name                       : chr  "FAIRFAX" "" "MONTGOMERY" "KERN" ...
#  $ primary_place_of_performance_state_code                        : chr  "VA" "" "MD" "CA" ...
#  $ primary_place_of_performance_state_name                        : chr  "VIRGINIA" "" "MARYLAND" "CALIFORNIA" ...
#  $ award_or_idv_flag                                              : chr  "AWARD" "AWARD" "AWARD" "AWARD" ...
#  $ award_type_code                                                : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
#  $ award_type                                                     : chr  "DO" "DELIVERY ORDER" "DO" "DO" ...
#  $ type_of_contract_pricing_code                                  : chr  "J" "J" "3" "S" ...
#  $ type_of_contract_pricing                                       : chr  "FIXED PRICE" "FIXED PRICE" "OTHER (NONE OF THE ABOVE)" "COST NO FEE" ...
#  $ award_description                                              : chr  "PURCHASE OF ROUTERS, SERVERS, AND ANCILLARY EQUIPMENT. USED WORLD-WIDE IN SUPPORT OF MISSION." "LOCKSMITH SUPPLIES" "RFP FOR IDIQ CONTRACT - MULTIPLE AWARD" "BASIC CLEANING SERVICES" ...
#  $ product_or_service_code                                        : chr  "7490" "4510" "R405" "S201" ...
#  $ product_or_service_code_description                            : chr  "MISCELLANEOUS OFFICE MACHINES" "PLUMBING FIXTURES AND ACCESSORIES" "OPERATIONS RESEARCH & QUANTITATIVE" "CUSTODIAL JANITORIAL SERVICES" ...
#  $ naics_description                                              : chr  "WIRED TELECOMMUNICATIONS CARRIERS" "OTHER SUPPORT ACTIVITIES FOR ROAD TRANSPORTATION" "ENGINEERING SERVICES" "JANITORIAL SERVICES" ...
#  $ domestic_or_foreign_entity                                     : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ country_of_product_or_service_origin_code                      : chr  "USA" "DEU" "NAN" "USA" ...
#  $ extent_competed_code                                           : chr  "A" "A" "" "D" ...
#  $ extent_competed                                                : chr  "FULL AND OPEN COMPETITION" "FULL AND OPEN COMPETITION" "" "FULL AND OPEN COMPETITION AFTER EXCLUSION OF SOURCES" ...
#  $ parent_award_type_code                                         : chr  "" "B" "" "" ...
#  $ parent_award_type                                              : chr  "" "IDC" "" "" ...
#  $ cost_or_pricing_data_code                                      : chr  "N" "N" "" "N" ...
#  $ cost_or_pricing_data                                           : chr  "NO" "NO" "" "NO" ...
#  $ multi_year_contract_code                                       : chr  "N" "N" "N" "N" ...
#  $ multi_year_contract                                            : chr  "NO" "NO" "NO" "NO" ...
```